# Prime number related scheduling problem

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, prime-numbers

In my recent math exploration, I came across a certain "fun-looking" problem that perhaps some of you may find interesting.

Suppose you have the $r$ guards, each with a strange schedule as follows: take $r$ consecutive primes starting with $5$, ($p_1=5,p_2=7,p_3=11,\ldots$) and $r$ integers of $s_i$ such that $0 \leq s_i \leq p_i-1$. If Guard $i$ is on duty at hour $x_i\in \mathbb{Z}$, then he is available at the times $\{x_i+kp_i,x_i+kp_i+s_i\}$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ (including negative integers).

The question is: how do we create a schedule, by choosing $\{x_i\}$ and $\{s_i\}$, such that we can achieve the longest period time where at any point, at least one guard is on duty?

For example, if $r=2$, the longest period of time is 4 hours by choosing $x_1=0,s_1=2$ and $x_2=1,s_2=2$. First guard is on duty at hours $\{\ldots,0,2,5,7,10,12,\ldots\}$ and the second guard at hours $\{\ldots,1,3,8,10,15,17,22,\ldots\}$, hence there is a guard on duty at the consecutive hours $\{0,1,2,3\}$.